# Why does std::binary_search use ForwardIterator, not RandomIterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am amazing that how does it compute the `middle` while it use ForwardIterator which does not support `auto middle = first + (last - first) / 2;`.

Comment: [Iterator tag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) dispatch: the actual implementation looks at the iterator tag and uses the appropriate method (likely via `std::advance` or an internal similar method). However, to search for something, `ForwardIterator` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `std::binary_search()` is notionally equivalent (for the non-comparator version) to

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  bool binary_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
{
  first = std::lower_bound(first,last,val);
  return (first!=last && !(val<*first));
}
```

where `std::lower_bound()` can be specialised for different iterators as needed (e.g. using `std::distance()` and `std::advance()` for `ForwardIterator` and other techniques for different iterators if appropriate for the implementation).   Bear in mind that `Bidirectional` and `RandomAccess` iterators are specialisations of `ForwardIterator`.

Answer (score 2):

Of cource you can count the number of elements even if it's not a random iterator.

If it's a random iterator, you can get it in a constant time by just `last - first`, if not, at least you can advance `first` one by one until `last`, and get the count at a linear complexity.

What should to implement is to dispatch it according to the iterator tag, here's an example of the implmentation image of `std::advance`, showing how to dispatch according to the iterator's type:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
inline void __advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n,
input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (n--) ++i;
}
template <class ForwardIterator, class Distance>
inline void __advance(ForwardIterator& i, Distance n,
forward_iterator_tag)
{
    advance(i, n, input_iterator_tag());
}
template <class BidiectionalIterator, class Distance>
inline void __advance(BidiectionalIterator& i, Distance n,
bidirectional_iterator_tag)
{
    if (n >= 0)
        while (n--) ++i;
    else
        while (n++) --i;
}
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Distance>
inline void __advance(RandomAccessIterator& i, Distance n,
random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    i += n;
}
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
inline void advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n)
{
    __advance(i, n, iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category());
}
```

Comment: But I am afraid that ForwardIterator still does not support such an expression `first + count`.

Comment: @acgtyrant It doesn't. The implementaion need to distinguish(dispatch) these cases. BTW: The implementation of `std::distance(first, last)` will do this for you.

Comment: @acgtyrant I've added an example about dispatch.